# Keep Knockout from running isValid() on page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I want to add a data attribute (data-invalid) to a text field if it is invalid and remove it if it is valid. Here's the html and js:

```
<form data-bind="submit: submitFields">
   First Name: <input type="text" runat="server" ID="FirstName" data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'blur', attr: { 'data-invalid': !firstName.isValid()}"/>
   <br/>
   <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

var viewModel;

viewModel = function() {
    self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true,
        notify: 'always'
    });

    //sets errors to an array of the error messages?
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, observable: false })

    self.submitFields = function(formElement) {
        if (self.errors().length > 0) {
           self.errors.showAllMessages();
           return;
        }
        //submit
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

And a fiddle to test it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/frontenderman/HhtEZ/2/

My problem is that firstName.IsValid() runs on pageload. Is there an elegant way to get around this? All I can think of is doing something like subscribing to firstName and using a flag to set the data-attribute to null on the first run through my view model and then returning !firstName.isValid() on any of the subsequent runs.

Comment: more curious as to why you want a data- attribute on the element, when  your underlying view model is already maintaining that state for you?  if you dont want the validation rule to execute, you can include an onlyif option (takes a function) to let it know when you want the rule executing.

Comment: It's to reuse a css attribute selector that is already being used by server side validation.